# How to put synctex file in different directory than pdf without segmentation fault?

Tags: pdftex, forward-inverse-search

I want to put output files (`.pdf`) into a `_out` dir and auxiliary files such as `.synctex.gz` or `.toc` into a `_aux` subdir.

From the help it seems that the `-d` option is what allows one to do it, but if I try to use it I get a Segmentation fault at the end.

Am I using it wrong?

```
echo '\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
a
\clearpage
a
\end{document}' > a.tex
mkdir _aux _out

pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=1 -output-directory _aux "a.tex"
synctex view -i "5:1:a.tex" -o "_aux/a.pdf"
echo $?
```

gives the good output (page 2) and `0` exit status but:

```
mv _aux/a.pdf _out/
synctex view -i "5:1:a.tex" -o "_out/a.pdf" -d "../_aux/"
echo $?
```

gives the good output + a line:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

and `139` exit status

and:

```
synctex view -i "5:1:a.tex" -o "_out/a.pdf" -d "_aux/"
echo $?
```

gives just:

```
This is SyncTeX command line utility, version 1.2
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

and `139` exit status.

Version: 1.2 on Ubuntu 12.10 from `texlive-full` package.

Comment: Is this still a problem with the current distribution?

Comment: @cfr hasn't changed on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: I have version 1.2 from TeX Live 2015. It works fine here. I can't reproduce the segmentation fault at all. So either it is because Ubuntu's TL is too old and something has been fixed since (not in `synctex` if it's the same version but maybe something else has changed) or it is something to do with Ubuntu's packaging. (How they are building the binaries, for example, or something necessary not getting included in the package.)

Comment: @cfr thanks for the info! The Ubuntu version is 2013.20140215-1 (I think that means 2013?). I will open a bug on the Ubuntu tracker and link from here.

Comment: @cfr Tested on 15.04 and seems to work. Yay!

Comment: Good to know..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Ubuntu 14.04 the situation was the same, texlive version 2013.20140215-1

But then I've tried Ubuntu 15.04 in Vagrant, texlive package version 2014.20141024-2ubuntu1, and the following worked:

```
mv _aux/a.pdf _out/
synctex view -i "5:1:a.tex" -o "_out/a.pdf" -d "../_aux/"
echo $?
```

Seems fixed then.